# How to retrieve all the rows except first row in PlSql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a basic sql query

```
SELECT ACC_AMNT FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ACC_ID = 10
```

this returns 2 rows What I would like to do is to get data after first row

how do I do that?

Comment: There is no inherent order to rows in a heap organized query.  Your query does not have an `order by` to determine the order of rows.  So any row in the result set could happen to be the first row returned and that could change over time.  Do you really want to ignore one arbitrary row?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: You can filter by rownum (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) such as `SELECT ACC_AMNT FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ACC_ID = 10 and rownum > 1;` but as @JustinCave states, the order of rows returned is not likely to be consistent over time meaning any output based on the ACC_AMNT is likely to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
>  select *    
>   from (select level , rownum rn
>            from dual 
>         connect by level < 30
>          -- here may be your code
>          -- you can order, and after get needed data
>         )  where rn > 1
```